# Rebar3 failed to fetch dependencies in docker container

Tags: erlang-otp, rebar3

Rebar3 dependencies installing locally but when I'm trying to run it inside the container raising error for all dependencies e.g:

```
#0 1.936 ===> Failed to fetch and copy dep: {git,"https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb.git",
#0 1.936                                   {ref,
#0 1.936                                       "073349423408e4bae08c90f8d16fee5317e45263"}}
```

Base image: `erlang:alpine`

OTP version: `26.0.1`

Rebar3 version: `3.20.0`

Answer (score 0):

Git was not installed on my container and it fixed by adding following code to Dockerfile:

```
RUN apk add git
```